# How to open a lot of tabs in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the case that I have a webpage like [this](https://deal5star.com/get-260-courses-udemy-now-for-free-for-a-limited-period/) i would like to use the console to open all hyperlinks in a new tab so I dont have to ctrl+click everyone indiviadually, is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Gather all the links into an array.
- Loop over the array.
- Open a new window for each link and populate it with the `href` from the link.

`Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href]")).forEach(function(link){ window.open(link.href);} );`

Comment: Why the downvote? Have you copied this code into your Console and tried it? I have.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: I managed to do the array and the loop, but I dont know how to open the links

Comment: @MarcosRobles The code includes that part. It's the `window.open(...)` part.